# FirebaseUser instance not null. Is it retrieving the first registered user on the same device even after clearing data?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have the following case using one physical device:

1. User authenticate and signs in the app with (123)-456-7890 phone number. User has "User UID" gets created in Firebase Authentication.
2. Now I go to app info--> clear data. Use the same (123)-456-7890 phone number, and I do have method:

   ```
   private boolean isUserNewUser(Task<AuthResult> task) {
       return task.getResult() != null && task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
   }
   ```

   that checks if the user is a new user or not. Since it is the same phone number, the second user will not have the possibility to create a new User UID in Firebase Authentication, as a result won't authenticate.
3. Now, I close the app, launch it again, and I do have a method set in the first launcher activity that gets triggered and user instance is not null.

   ```
   mAuthListener = firebaseAuth -> {
           FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
           if (user != null) {
               //User is signed in
               ActivitiesHelper.intentActivityLauncher(this,
                       HomeActivity.class, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
           } else {
               //User is signed out
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
           }
       };
   ```

**Question:** 
How can it be possible that the callback is returning a non null instance of FirebaseUser?

Answer (score 1):

. According to **FirebaseInstanceId** doc, Instance ID is stable except when:

- App deletes Instance ID
- App is restored on a new device
- User uninstalls/reinstall the app
- User clears app data

However every time you launch your app after clearing its data , a different Token is returned through the `FirebaseInstanceIdService` `onTokenRefreshed()` callback.

this is the normal behaviour of the service .

i advice you to go [there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and read about creating Custom Tokens